# Mongoose Date Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express-handlebars

I am using MongoDB, Mongoose, Express and Express Handlebars.

I have an `<input type="date">` in my form, that posts to database, and my mongoose schema is defined like this:

```
var recordsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
   scheduled: Date,
});
```

The form inserts the time, but the output looks something like this:

> Fri Oct 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)

I want to format it so it appears as:

> Fri Oct 26 2018

And not have anything else.

I tried using `toString()` method in the Handlebars template, but it doesn't work and server throws an error.

This is how it looks on the Express-Handlebars side:

```
{{ this.scheduled }} {{ this.scheduled.toString() }}
```

Can someone please let me know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `.toDateString()`? and you can use custom getters inside schema to get the desired format.

Comment: Hi Shiv, yes I tried toDateString() but that doesn't work either. how should I change the schema?

Comment: I think you have take sub string from the date object like : Date().substr(0,15)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a custom getter in the schema to get the formatted date string as expected.

```
var recordsSchema = new Schema ({
  scheduled: Date,
  get: value => value.toDateString()
});
```